# A confusion on a logical step in the proof that $x^2+y^2-2ixy$ is not an analytic polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, proof-verification

To show that $x^2+y^2-2ixy$ is not an analytic polynomial. We assume that it is a analytic polynomial and try to contradict. First we write
$$x^2+y^2-2ixy=\sum_{k=0}^N \alpha_k(x+iy)^k$$
Since this holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}$, we can put $y=0$ to obtain
$$x^2=\sum_{k=0}^N \alpha_kx^k$$
which can be re-written as
$$\alpha_0+\alpha_1x+(\alpha_2-1)x^2+\ldots+\alpha_Nx^N=0 \,\, \cdots \, (\star)$$
This holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So we put $x=0$ to obtain $\alpha_0=0$. *Now we divide $(\star)$ by $x$ and put $x=0$* to obtain $\alpha_1=0$. In this way we obtain $\alpha_2=1, \alpha_3=0$ and so on. Thus the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^N \alpha_k(x+iy)^k$ becomes $(x+iy)^2$, which is $x^2-y^2+2ixy$. Hence by assuming $x^2+y^2-2ixy$ to be an analytic polynomial, we are led to obtain $$x^2+y^2-2ixy=x^2-y^2+2ixy, \,\text{for all}\,\, x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$
which is a false statement. Contradiction. My confusion is with the step when I *divide $(\star)$ by $x$ and put $x=0$*. Is this is a legal step? Can we divide something by $x$ and then put $x=0$? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly legal; all you're doing is stating in other words that if two real-valued polynomials on $\mathbf{R}$ (in this case, $x^2$ and $\sum_{k=0} \alpha_k x^k$) have the same values everywhere, then they also have the same coefficients—and I think this claim should be clear without proof.

EDIT: actually, sorry, this isn't quite true: you can't "set $x$ to $0$" in the equation $\frac{\alpha_0}{x} + \alpha_1 + (\alpha_2-1) x + \cdots + \alpha_N x^{N-1} = 0$, because this gives a divide-by-zero error in the term $\alpha_0/x$. But the point you were driving at—equal values imply equal coefficients—is true. (If you need another proof, then consider the first, second, etc. derivatives of each side of the equation, evaluated at 0.)